# is it possible to use jqassistant output with graphlytic?

Tags: neo4j, jqassistant, graphlytic

I'm currently struggling with circular dependencies and wanted to see all classes that are dependant on my desired class transitively.

I figured jqassistant is a tool to go to. I am already familiar with graphlytic, but can i somehow import the result of jqassistant into it? As far as i know jqassistant outputs some kind of html report.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out after reading jqassistant docs (duh), it is possible to run separate neo4j database with simple
`mvn jqassistant:server`
running on default ports, which graphlytic can freely access.
That is actually much better choice.